# Applying !important to whole CSS layout

Tags: css

I want to apply `!important` to all `div`,`p`,`pre`, and `span` elements, overwriting all properties which are currently written inline. For example:

```
.contpost p,pre,span,div{
    color:#4c4c4c !important;
}
```

Does this color now apply to the whole page and specifically to that `div`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its not very clear what your asking here. id recommend checking these links, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you mean this? It's a bit vague without more information.

```
.contpost p,
.contpost pre,
.contpost span,
.contpost div{
    color:#4c4c4c!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id to the body tag, say

```
<body id="container">
```

and then use

```
#container div{color:value !important;} 
#container p{color:value !important;}
#container pre{color:value !important;}
#container span{color:value !important;}
```

OR just combine them into one:

```
 #container div, #container p, #container pre, #container span{color:value !important;}
```